# Format text in string as hh:mm:ss, hours only when needed

Tags: c#, string, text, format

I'd like to format some text in a string. So if I input the text `0759`, it should format it to `07:59 (minutes and seconds)`.

Same it should work like this (pseudocode)

> input 759 -> output 07:59
>
> input 10545 -> output 01:05:45 (hours, minutes, seconds)
>
> input 5 -> output 00:05

I thought about using `string.Format()` but I as a newbie I don't really know how to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: 7 minutes and 89 seconds? Is that what you want? wouldn't it be 8 minutes and 29 seconds

Comment: Have you checked out MSDN on `string.Format`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx ...if these are times, have you thought about parsing them into `TimeSpan`'s?

Comment: How do you get that input ?

Comment: I've actually read about TimeSpan's, however I didn't see a way to convert a format like 0789 to 07:89. I saw `TimeSpan.FromSeconds()`, but that won't work in this case because it's not 789 seconds (which would be 13:15).

Comment: @Jacobus21: What is 89 seconds? Is that an invalid input or is that 60+19 seconds which would add a minute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to jump through a couple of different hoops to get this accomplished. You'll need to cast your numbers to string, and pad them out the appropriate number of places (6). Then you have to call DateTime.ParseExact with the appropriate information. Code below should work for everything you need:

```
void Main()
{

var i = 10545;
var t = i.ToString().PadLeft(6, '0');

var d = DateTime.ParseExact(t, "HHmmss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss}", d));
}
```

You need to use 24 hour format to get the exact hours, minues, seconds you want. Anything over 235959 will error, so you'll have to handle that differently.

see [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) for DateTime.ParseExact() and [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for format codes

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method:

```
public static TimeSpan? TryParseTimeSpan(string input)
{
    TimeSpan? ts = (TimeSpan?)null;
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
    {
        input = input.Trim();
        int length = input.Length % 2 == 0 ? input.Length : input.Length + 1;
        int count = length / 2;

        if(count > 3) return null;

        input = input.PadLeft(count * 2, '0');

        string[] validFormats = new[] { "HHmmss", "mmss", "ss" };
        DateTime dt;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(input, validFormats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
            ts = dt.TimeOfDay; 
    }
    return ts;
}
```

However, it doesn't accept a second part of 89 seconds, that is not a valid input (imho).

Tested with this sample input:

```
List<string> inputs = new List<string> { "78", "10545", "5" };
IEnumerable<TimeSpan> timeSpans = inputs
    .Select(i => TryParseTimeSpan(i))
    .Where(ts => ts.HasValue)
    .Select(ts => ts.Value);
foreach (TimeSpan ts in timeSpans)
    Console.WriteLine(ts.ToString());
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/maguQ0)</kbd>

Output:

```
01:05:45
00:00:05
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(ts.Hours == 0 ? ts.ToString("hh:mm") : ts.ToString());` will satisfy the requirement of dropping the hours column if zero.

Comment: @Peter: yes, i have focused my answer on parsing the TimeSpans. Once you have it you can use TimeSpan.ToString with custom format strings.

Comment: Because of the original question tags include `string` `text` and `format`, I felt this was an important part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> inputs = new List<string> { "78", "10545", "5" };
IEnumerable<TimeSpan> timeSpans = inputs
    .Select(i => TryParseTimeSpan(i))
    .Where(ts => ts.HasValue)
    .Select(ts => ts.Value);
foreach (TimeSpan ts in timeSpans)
    Console.WriteLine(ts.ToString());
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 0):

First you need to configure the format for 00:00 you would want to use the format string `"00:00"`

```
string input = 0789
input = String.Format("00:00",input); //input is now 07:89
```

However this will not work for values that are more than 4 digits.  Using `TimeSpan` objects would be a better way to process these since they already have have minute & second components

TimeSpan: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx

Format source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx